Unittest asyncio patch object mock with nested coros
I want to mock the client of an async database client in unittest.
The functioncall of the client is like:
test.client.json().set(argumentsforquery)

The test looks like this:
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_client(self):  
    self.test.client = AsyncMock()

    with patch.object(self.test.client.json, 'set', return_value='FooBar') as mock:
        print(await mock())
        # FooBar
        print(await self.test.client.json.set())
        # FooBar
        print(await self.test.client.json().set())
        # AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'set'

My problem is that the mocked object self.test.client.json does not return the attribute set like in the third print-statement shown. I tried to patch self.test.client with json and add the set-attribute as return_value as type AsyncMock() with the same result.
Any ideas how to get FooBar by calling await self.test.client.json().set()?
